# nodejs API request function error handling crashes app

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, request

I'm trying to make an API call and pass it into a function that stores it into MongoDB. The problem is that the entire site crashes when I try to handle errors instead of redirecting to the error page. All my other functions work, it's just the request function containing the API call that doesn't.

Instead of redirecting, I only get the error messages in the terminal.

Here's my code for it:

index.js

```
router.post('/',async function(req,res){
  var {title,date,loc,count, save,del,update,csv} = req.body;
  var {username} = req.session;
  console.log(req.body);
  var url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${loc}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`

  if(save){
    //weather api       
    request({ url: url, json: true }, async function (error, response) {
      if(error){
        throw new Error ('type error');
      }
      else{
        console.log('Current weather: '
                + response.body.main.temp
                + ' degrees celsius'
        );
        let w = JSON.stringify(response.body.main.temp);
        console.log(w)
        await db.addItem(username,title, loc, count, w, date);
      }
    });
    res.redirect('/');
  }
```

app.js

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Here is what my terminal looks like when the app crashes:

[image: terminal error message]

Comment: in the else statement of your `request()` callback you are not handling an error if it occurs there, which it does. You should first check if `response.body.main` is undefined. Since you do not, and it is undefined, when you try to read the property `temp` it throws this unhandled error and crashes the app

Comment: @about14sheep I added the check for reponse.body.main but the app still crashes the same way when I try it

Comment: is it the same error? maybe you try console logging what response is so you know how to navigate it

Comment: @about14sheep the response is undefined

Comment: this means you, or the `request` package you are using, is not calling the api correctly. I am seeing [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) that the package is deprecated. Also, have you tried adding and logging the third parameter for the callback, `body`?

Comment: @about14sheep I'm calling the api correctly as long as I fill in the city name in the page form. I tried adding body and it still crashed

Comment: if you put the exact url in the browser do you get results?

Comment: @about14sheep exact url of the api call?

Comment: yes, you can console log the `url` variable before the `request` call, copy/paste it into the browser and see whats returned. This can help you determine if the url is bad, or if the code you are using in the `request()` call is wrong

Comment: @about14sheep {"cod":"400","message":"Nothing to geocode"} was what the url gave me

Comment: seems like the `loc` variable youre passing into the url is incorrect, check that `loc` is being set correctly

Comment: @about14sheep that's because I purposely left it blank so I would get an error. The problem is that it won't redirect me to the error page when it occurs

Comment: oh lol sorry i misunderstood, you can use a `try/catch` block. Ill put an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not describe what to do if an error occurs in the else statement of the `request` call. So if an error occurs it will crash.

Since you are using `async...await` in the callback to insert into the db, you can get the functionality you want by wrapping it in a [`try...catch` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) and moving the redirect into the catch:

```
request({ url: url, json: true }, async function (error, response) {
  if(error){
    throw new Error ('type error');
   } else {
     try {
      console.log('Current weather: '
        + response.body.main.temp
        + ' degrees celsius'
      );
      let w = JSON.stringify(response.body.main.temp);
      console.log(w)
      await db.addItem(username,title, loc, count, w, date);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  }
});
```

However, the `throw new Error('type error')` will still cause the app to crash here. If you want to also redirect in this case, then you can add a `res.redirect('/')` there as well instead of throwing, or wrap the entire `request` call in a `try...catch` so that the catch block will also catch that thrown type error:

```
try {
   request({ url: url, json: true }, async function (error, response) {
      if(error){
        throw new Error ('type error');
      }
      else{
        console.log('Current weather: '
                + response.body.main.temp
                + ' degrees celsius'
        );
        let w = JSON.stringify(response.body.main.temp);
        console.log(w)
        await db.addItem(username,title, loc, count, w, date);
      }
    });
} catch (error) {
  res.redirect('/')
}
```